# The address space in OPC can be loaded dynamically?

Tags: opc

We are trying to make an OPC Server which includes a huge address space using a huge structure of objects and levels.

The problem is the following: when the SCADA tries to connect in order to read only one specific tag... the OPC Server expends around 47 minutes to serve the value, due to it needs to create the entire address space first.

My question is... Could we create the address space dynamically? But without any side effect like forcing the clients a re-connection.

I have read this option about how to create the address space:

- Automatically configured on the fly by an ‘intelligent’ server based on the names of the data items the client applications are currently requesting.

Which is in this link:

http://pgras.web.cern.ch/pgras/HtmlSpef/DA_Fundamentals.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Create a tree structure and only serve up the current branch when listing available tags. The current branch may contain nodes (other branches) or leaves (tags). When a client browses up or down, that node becomes the current branch.